# How to keep log4j's log file under WEB-INF in struts application

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I would like to keep my log4j's log file under WEB-INF of my struts2 application.Here is my log4j.xml file

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
     <log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">
           <appender name="APPLICATION" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
               <param name="file" value="${appRootPath}WEB-INF/log/application.log"/>
               <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm"/>
               <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                   <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5p %c %m%n"/>
               </layout>
           </appender>
           <logger name="mypackage">
               <level value="DEBUG"/>
                 <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
                 <appender-ref ref="APPLICATION"/>
               </logger>
           </log4j:configuration>
```

How to set **appRootPath**(web application context path) in my java code?I try like this

```
     ServletContext ctx = e.getServletContext();
     System.setProperty("appRootPath", ctx.getRealPath("/"));
```

but getRealPath() method returning path is not actually what I want. I want the path like this

```
    D:\dev\workspace\MyApp\WebContent\WEB-INF\log
```

So please share me some sample or resources.I use eclipse juno and window 7 in my development.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do this. There's no guarantee that the war will be exploded on disk, and even if it is, the container can set the code directories read-only, so you should never attempt to write to a location "inside" your webapp.